# Bundle ID not listed App store connect new app list (Xcode 11.4.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode11, apple-developer-account

I have created a developer account for two weeks, and now I want to submit my first App. However, when I click new app, the bundle ID list does NOT show the project I would like to submit, but It do show some projects I used to practice. I have look up a variety of solutions on internet, including sign out and log in again, or clean up my Safari data. I have suspected some reason, but I'm not quite sure if it right?

> 1. First doubt : some SDK import?

The Bundle ID shows on the list are some small project I used to practice when I was a beginner. Recently, I have tried to use some SDK like Facebook SDK and Firebase. Facebook and Firebase works fine on my simulator and iPhone devices. So I'm not quite think this might be the reason, nut just type on in case I missed something

> 2. Second doubt : Xcode version?

When I tried to using Firebase, since iOS 13.3.1 seems not to support, so I update my iPhone to iOS 13.4.1. However, the Xcode should also be updated to 11.4.1, otherwise it cannot connect to my devices. When I look up  the bundle IDs listed on App Store Connect, I think those projects are created before I updated Xcode. The project created after updated not showed on the list. But I have created too many projects to practice, so I'm not quite sure I remembered right. I suspect this might be the reason, anyone else met the same problem after updated Xcode?

By the way, there is also a strange thing confused me. I have deleted some projects I used to practiced on my MAC, but they stilled shown on the list... I have manually deleted on my Apple Developer Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/account and set up the app with its explicit bundle ID.

2) Then go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com > "Create new app" > Select the previously created bundle ID.

This does not really have anything to do with SDK usage or Xcode setup. (Automatic code signing might do some steps for you, but the most bullet-proof way is mentioned above)

Comment: Precision: in your account page, go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and add a bundle